# How to clean up this jQuery hover+wrap function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my function:

```
var add_cloud_zoom_wrapper = function() {
  $('#main-image').hover(function() {
    $('#main-image').wrap(function() {
      return '<a href=' + $(this).attr('src').replace(/\bproduct\b/, 'original') + ' class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom1" rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4, position: \'inside\'">';
    });
  });
}
```

The .wrap() alone works. I need this to work however, whenever the image is hovered over because I have another event where the image changes, so I'll need a new anchor tag to hover the newly embedded image each time. The other part of this is I need to remove the anchor tag with id="zoom1" before I wrap, otherwise we'll have additional/broken markup. What's the best way to clean this up?

My HTML is straight forward:

```
<img alt="foo" id="main-image" src="/assets/products/1051/product/Perspective_View-0.jpeg?1290039436" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question, but this may work:

```
var add_cloud_zoom_wrapper = function() {
    $('#main-image').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).wrap(function() {
            return '<a href=' + $(this).attr('src').replace(/\bproduct\b/, 'original') + ' class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom1" rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4, position: \'inside\'">';
        });
    }, function() {
        var link_element = $(this).closest('a');
        link_element.parent().append($(this));
        link_element.remove();
    });
};
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4HPXd/).

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work. What should I be doing in the example?

Comment: You can see it adds the link to the image on mouseover, and removes it on mouseout.

Comment: Lame question, but do you mouseover on the result frame? What's the process to see the HTML update? Rather confused with how to use the site is all.

Comment: Actually jsfiddle is pretty cool. The bottom right box is what you should be looking at. On mouseover the alt text (because the image is not found) turns blue (i.e. the link appeared), and on mouseout it gets removed. Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4HPXd/3/), I added some stuff so you can see the html in a textarea.